# Error- a __global__ function call must be configured

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I am writing a code for Big Integer Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division. But while compiling the code, I am getting this error, along with another error `error: a __global__ function must have a void return type`.

The code is 700 lines long and there are errors are multiple lines. Hence for convenience, I am attaching a link of my Google Colab notebook. Please check it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ASaea1oQLFO6eKILIBy0rN9BZEoScnRM#scrollTo=LzF9Pkebm3ky&uniqifier=2)

And here is the error I am getting

```
/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(94): error: a __global__ function must have a void return type

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(139): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "addition"

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(265): warning: variable "n" was declared but never referenced

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(367): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(381): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(390): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(442): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(456): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(465): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(533): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(538): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(548): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu(553): error: a __global__ function call must be configured

11 errors detected in the compilation of "/content/src/omp_cuda80.cu".
/bin/bash: /content/src/omp_cuda80: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think you need the most basic of CUDA tutorials, as right now, you just "guessed" how CUDA is written, and unsuprisingly, the guess is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you define a CUDA function using `__global__` you need to call it with the syntax

```
function<<<grid,block>>>(param1,param2,...);
```

You are calling them as

```
function(param1,param2,...);
```

That is why you get  `a __global__ function call must be configured`.

GPU functions also do not return a value, they must return `void`. You can get the return value in a pointer, and the copy it to CPU to inspect it if needed. There are other ways also, but it goes beyond the scope of this answer.